# Compilation failed for package 'RMongo' on Windows

Tags: r, devtools, rmongo

I am having trouble trying to install RMongo version 0.1.0. 
My code is as follows:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("tc/RMongo")
```

The system output that I'm getting is:

```
Downloading GitHub repo tc/RMongo@master
Installing RMongo
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.1/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save  \
  --no-restore CMD INSTALL  \
  "C:/XX/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpSGqhcG/devtools23d44de847da/tc-RMongo-9b6d1b1"  \
  --library="C:/XX/Documents/R/win-library/3.2" --install-tests 

* installing *source* package 'RMongo' ...
** libs

*** arch - i386
no DLL was created
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'RMongo'
* removing 'C:/XX/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/RMongo'
Error: Command failed (1)
```

I cannot use the install package method in R because I require the latest version of RMongo to support Mongo 3.0

Can't figure out why it does not work. Have tried to reinstall Rtools and devtools but the error still remains

My Session Info is as follows:

```
Session info --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
 system   x86_64, mingw32             
 ui       RStudio (0.99.467)          
 language (EN)                        
 collate  English_United States.1252  
 tz       Asia/Kuala_Lumpur           
 date     2015-10-09                  

Packages ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 package  * version date       source        
 curl       0.9.3   2015-08-25 CRAN (R 3.2.2)
 devtools * 1.9.1   2015-09-11 CRAN (R 3.2.2)
 digest     0.6.8   2014-12-31 CRAN (R 3.2.1)
 httr       1.0.0   2015-06-25 CRAN (R 3.2.2)
 magrittr   1.5     2014-11-22 CRAN (R 3.2.1)
 memoise    0.2.1   2014-04-22 CRAN (R 3.2.2)
 R6         2.1.1   2015-08-19 CRAN (R 3.2.2)
 stringi    0.5-5   2015-06-29 CRAN (R 3.2.1)
 stringr    1.0.0   2015-04-30 CRAN (R 3.2.1)
```

My java version is version 8 update 51
Wondering if I have missed out any steps required?

Comment: Which version of Java do you have? I think you need both 32 and 64 bits version to be installed.

Answer (score 1):

Visit the link: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RMongo/index.html

From the downloads section, download the RMongo binaries as per your system requirments.

After you finish downloading the required binaries type the command below:

`install.packages("PATH_TO_DOWNLOADED_FILE", repos = NULL, type="source")`