# Error while installing RMongo 0.1.0 (Error: Command failed (1))

Tags: r, git, rmongo

I have followed the following procedure to install RMongo from GitHub

```
library(devtools)
library(httr)
set_config(use_proxy(url="", port=9090, username="xxxx",password="xxx"))
install_github("tc/RMongo")
```

But i am getting the following error

```
install_github("tc/RMongo")
Downloading GitHub repo tc/RMongo@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/tc/RMongo/zipball/master
Installing RMongo

C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.0/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save  \
  --no-restore --quiet CMD INSTALL  \
  "C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpkLyleH/devtools24a85742c3f/tc-RMongo-cba187f"  \
  --library="C:/Users/xxxx/Documents/R/win-library/3.3" --install-tests  
 * installing *source* package 'RMongo' ...  
 ** libs

*** arch - i386
no DLL was created
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'RMongo'
* removing 'C:/Users/xxxx/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/RMongo'  
Error: Command failed (1)
```

I have installed Rtools as well..

Let me know how do i proceed with this issue.

Comment: Installed RTools 3.4 or 3.3? Use 3.4

Comment: I have installed RTools 3.4. But still its giving the same error. Is there any Java dependency.

Comment: Check my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40914667/1931296